# Exception calling "Invoke" with "1" argument(s):"Element 'Objs' with namespace name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04' was not found

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm trying to install and update package through powershell, below is the script. session is successfully created, but when invoking a remote script, I'm getting an error.

**Script:**

```
$file = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\Data\SitecorePackageDeployer\SampleTDSProject.update"
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username prem -Password **** -ConnectionUri http://test
$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create("Start-ScriptSession -ScriptBlock {Install-UpdatePackage -Path $file -UpgradeAction Upgrade -InstallMode Update ; Start-Sleep -Seconds 10; [PSCustomObject]@{'IsComplete'=$true}}")
$job = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

**Error:**

```
Exception calling "Invoke" with "1" argument(s): "Element 'Objs' with namespace name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04' was not found. Line 3, position 2."
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SPE\5.1.0\ConvertFrom-CliXml.ps1:22 char:9
+         $deserializer = $ctor.Invoke($xr)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : XmlException

Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s): "Non-static method requires a target."
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SPE\5.1.0\ConvertFrom-CliXml.ps1:24 char:16
+ ...      while (!$type.InvokeMember("Done", "InvokeMethod,NonPublic,Insta ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TargetException
```

[image]

Comment: My fix was to downgrade to Sitecore SPE 5.0. I Hope it will be fixet asap

Comment: Can you provide the details of which version of SPE and SPE Remoting packages you used?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely related to the fact you are using incompatible versions of the SPE Remoting package and SPE.

- If you are using SPE 5.1 then you should be using SPE Remoting 5.1.
- If you are using SPE 5.0 then you should be using SPE Remoting 5.0 (or 5.0.1).

To get the SPE version you can run the following command from within the SPE Console or ISE: `$PSVersionTable`

[image]

To get the SPE Remoting version you can run the following command from with the Windows PowerShell Console or ISE: `Get-Module -Name SPE`

[image]

Comment: How do you check this exactly?

Comment: Updated answer with the steps.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra details, confirm that we have the correct versions, now I'm hitting an issue where I can see the script tries to hit /sitecore%20modules/PowerShell/Services/RemoteScriptCall.ashx , but it's being redirected to our customer login page and the request returns the HTML not the XML powershell is expecting, so we get the error described in this post. I'll check security setup again but this may be related to the way we have our auth set up for customers

Comment: You may check to see if the Spe.IdentityServer.config patch if IS is used.

Comment: Thanks, yes we are using SI and the patch is enabled